# Set of General Linear Position with Nonzero Measure

Tags: measure-theory, euclidean-geometry, lebesgue-measure

I came to the following question, but I don't have quite a good idea how to approach.

Can a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n  , n\ge 2$ with nonzero measure be in a general linear position?

I believe that, since this is quite a simple question, this would already have an answer, but I could not find it.

Comment: Can you define precisely the concept of *general linear position*?

Comment: I do not follow the definition. How do $m$ and $n$ relate? Say, $m=1$, how is it that: "any $2$ points...is not in a $1$-dimensional hyperplane...: ? What if $m>n$? You could google two-point set, and find related results, e.g. http://www.math.unt.edu/~mauldin/papers/no100.pdf or http://im0.p.lodz.pl/~sglab/szymon/BGRZ.pdf

Comment: @Mirko Sorry, I mean that for all $1\le m<n$, any $m+2$ points in $A$ is not in a $m$-domensional hyperplane of $\mathbb R ^n $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, at least if $A$ is assumed to be measurable. Let $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the projection to the first coordinate. For every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, if $A$ is in general linear position, then $\pi^{-1}(t)$ is finite, and therefore has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. So Fubini's Theorem implies that $A$ has measure zero.